# Is it possible to write C++ app for Samsung Smart TV with access to USB device

Tags: c++, samsung-smart-tv

Is there an easy howto on writing C++ app for Samsung Smart TV that should be able to run in background (so not an HTML/JS applet) and access /dev/ttyUSBx device plugged in the TV?

Do they have some API to access /dev/ttyUSBx or it will be a simple Linux app? Do they allow to load such apps? Is there a toolchain to compile such apps?

Comment: FYI: http://developer.samsung.com/smarttv

Comment: @Robᵩ there are no info about low level apps (servers) on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least according to Samsung, "No."

> > > Q: Do you support C++ in the SDK?
> > >
> > > A: No, Samsung platform only supports web technologies based apps (JS, CSS, HTML, FLASH)

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Support/FAQList?page=1&faqCateID=2

Comment: So, no way to support USB hardware?

Comment: Samsung SmartTVs have JavaScript API for downloading files to the USB storage (flash disks) and saving text files there, but nothing more. Samsung SmartTVs support standard HW like keybord or mouse and some Samsung specific HW - e.g. their WiFi adapter or camera (for Skype video calls).

Answer (score 1):

In the SDK 4.5 will include Native Client technology, NaCl, Currently supported languages ​​are C and C + +. For more information: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d17/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For Samsung SmartTVs you cannot use C++, the only allowed language/technology is HTML/JavaScript/CSS and Flash (not used much).

Majority of the applications are JavaScript based.

Might be you can have some exclusive agreement with the Samsung, since e.g. Skype is most probably not developed in JavaScript and the AngryBirds I heard are C++ as well.

BR

STeN